# Display Date in ggplot as x axis

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

My data has the format of

```
["201301",1111],["201302",1111],["201702",2222],["201603",3333].
```

However, when I try to plot it as a bar chart, it looks not nice since the x value was considered as a number. There is a large gap between years. 
[image]

Is it possible to eliminate the gap?

Comment: can you add some data with the code which you have tried producing the given plot? Most probably, it will be eliminated if you treat `V1` as factors.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to display monthly data where year and month are coded in the format "YYYYMM" in variable `V1`.

I can reproduce the issue by

```
# create sample data
years <- 2013:2017
DF <- data.frame(V1 = 100 * rep(years, each = 12) + rep(1:12, length(years)),
                 V2 = rep(1:12, length(years)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(V1, V2)) +
         geom_col()
```

[image]

To plot these monthly data, `V1` needs to be converted into full-fledged dates, e.g., `201304` becomes the date `2013-04-01`. So, each year-month is mapped to the first day of the month.

With help of the `lubridate` package we get

```
ggplot(DF, aes(lubridate::ymd(V1, truncated = 1L), V2)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

`ggplot()` recognizes that the x axis is now a `Date` class and scales accordingly. Using a `Date` scale has the benefit that it scales correctly even if  data points are missing.